# Read query parameter from URL in Kibana-5.1 search query i.e as a placeholder

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am new to Kibana and using it for visualising the data present in Elastic Search.
I am trying to create dynamic dashboard i.e. by using saved search indexes having field values as variable.

**What I want**

Want to use place holders in the query which can be populated from URL parameters and then search results rendered in dashboard.
So that user can search results by providing some input instead of fixed query.
Can it be done in Kibana? If not, is there any better visualisation tool other than Kibana to serve this purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Dashboard View there is actually a searchbar where you can just fire normal Matchqueries and its easy to filter i.e:

1. Create a table with terms aggregation for one of the fields a user might be interested in.
2. Click on one of the Terms in the Dashboard
3. A filter can be seen under the searchbar and all elements in the dashboard will be filtered with it.

   - If you have line charts users can zoom into the charts to see only information of the zoomed in timeframe
   - Barcharts are interactive like tables

Play around a bit. Kibana is very powerful you just have to find the right visualizations.

Comment: That options seems great didn't know that! Worked for me. But one problem still left - if we have multiple panels in the dashboard, can I apply query filter to each panel differently rather than applying it to all.

Comment: For ex-
`http://<url>/kibana#/dashboard?_a=(filters:!(),options:(darkTheme:!t),panels:!((col:1,id:DirectReportees,panelIndex:1,row:1,size_x:12,size_y:2,type:visualization),(col:1,id:UserMetrics,panelIndex:2,row:3,size_x:11,size_y:2,type:visualization)),query:(query_string:(analyze_wildcard:!t,query:'ManagerLogin:xyz')),title:'New%20Dashboard',uiState:())`

So is there any option to apply query **ManagerLogin:xyz** to only panel1 rather than both panels.